# Hide ActionBar title

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar

I use `toolbar`  and I set title with a help `TextView`(for center title)

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tbFriends"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/background"
        android:theme="@style/ToolbarStyle" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvToolbarTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            style="@style/ToolbarTitleStyle"
            />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Also I need a back arrow. I did:

```
private void setupToolBar() {
    tvToolbarTitle.setText(R.string.title_toolbar_friends);
    setSupportActionBar(tbFriends);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    tbFriends.setNavigationOnClickListener(v -> onBackPressed());
}
```

And after that  I have:
[image]

How can I hide actionbar custom  title?
I tried:

```
   <style name="ToolbarStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:displayOptions">useLogo|showHome</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/NoTitleText</item>
        <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/NoTitleText</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NoTitleText">
        <item name="android:textSize">0sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#00000000</item>
    </style>
```

and

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

but it did not help

Comment: Don't think you need this `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)` also you can do the navigation in the manifest, by specifying a parent for an activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the activity's label attribute value to "" blank in the manifest. this will remove appname title.

If label not available then add lable="". This will also remove name on toolbar

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

to

```
android:label=""
```

Comment: it's helped.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but that will hide your app's title once in split mode as well